# encryption insert word, and key where the key will move the letters to the right in the alphabet

Tags: python, encryption

Here is my code that asks the user for an input of a letter and input of a digit. My code shifts the letter to the right in the alphabet by how ever big the 'digit' is.

```
def code_char(character, number):
characterOrd = ord(character)
characterNew = characterOrd + number
if 65 <= characterOrd <= 90:
    characterNew = characterOrd + number
    if characterNew > 90:
        characterNewi = characterNew - 26
        return (chr(characterNewi))
    elif characterNew <= 90:
        return (chr(characterNew))
elif 97 <= characterOrd <= 122:
    characterNew = characterOrd + number
    if characterNew > 122:
        characterNewi = characterNew - 26
        return (chr(characterNewi))
    elif characterNew <= 122:
        return (chr(characterNew))
```

(Dont worry about the indents in my code, they just didn't come up when i copied and pasted from my python program - i have tested it and it works fine - for example inserting 'a' give 'b' and inserting 'Z' gives 'A'.

I was wondering how to use this function in a new function where it asks for an 8 character long string 'abcdefgh' and an 8 digit long number '11111111' and shift all the corresponding letters to the right in the alphabet, so my example would return 'bcdefghi'.
The tricky thing is i would rather work with strings than ordinances like i have in my function at the top.

Any tips or methods would be appreciated, but my knowledge on python is limited, so it would be nice if basic functions were used.

Comment: `''.join(chr(ord(k) + 1) for k in 'abcdefgh')` ?

Comment: How does the the 8 digit long number affect the function? What if the input was `'abcdefgh'` and `'48151623'`? And what's an ordinance?

Comment: so, offsets are always single-digit?

Comment: to first responder, i dont know what you mean.
to second reply if the input was 'abcdefgh' and '48151623', it would return 'ejdiflik'. an ordinance (what i heard my teacher call it) is a letters or characters number value, which have preset values in python - for example ord('A') gives 65, ord('Z') gives 90, and the lowercase alphabet is 97-122.
and to the third replier, yeah the offsets are always single digits.

Comment: @user3382238 I added to my answer below to show how it would work by updating you function, as well as some tricks to clean up the code. If anything doesn't make sense or want more information on just ask.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to use your function in a for loop and use zip to combine the strings and offsets.

```
def new_func(string, offsets):
    outstr = ""
    for char, num in zip(string, offsets):
        outstr += code_char(char, int(num))
    print(outstr)
```

The bonus points one liner version:

```
print("".join([code_char(char, int(num)) for char, num in zip(string, offsets)]))
```

See it in action (using python3):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = input("string: ")
    offsets = input("offsets: ")
    if len(string) != len(offsets):
        print("They must be the same length!")
    else:
        print("".join([code_char(char, int(num)) 
                       for char, num in zip(string, offsets)]))

# string: abcdefgh
# offsets: 12345678
# bdfhjlnp
```

---

You can also simply update your existing function to meet the new needs.

```
# Modified original
def code_char_string(character_string, offsets):
    out_string = ""
    for character, offset in zip(character_string, offsets):
        number = int(offset)
        characterOrd = ord(character)
        characterNew = characterOrd + number
        if 65 <= characterOrd <= 90:
            characterNew = characterOrd + number
            if characterNew > 90:
                characterNewi = characterNew - 26
                out_string += (chr(characterNewi))
            elif characterNew <= 90:
                out_string+= (chr(characterNew))
        elif 97 <= characterOrd <= 122:
            characterNew = characterOrd + number
            if characterNew > 122:
                characterNewi = characterNew - 26
                out_string += (chr(characterNewi))
            elif characterNew <= 122:
                out_string += (chr(characterNew))
    return out_string
```

You can also use the following tricks to make it easier to read.

```
# Simplified readable version
def code_char_string_compact(character_string, offsets):
    out_string = ""
    for cord, number in zip([ord(x) for x in character_string], [int(x) for x in offsets]):
        newchar = cord + number
        if 65 <= cord <= 90:
            out_string += chr(newchar - 26) if newchar > 90 else chr(newchar)
        elif 97 <= cord <= 122:
            out_string += chr(newchar - 26) if newchar > 122 else chr(newchar)
    return out_string
```

Your function can also be simplified down to a lengthy one liner.

```
# oneliner awesomeness
def code_char_one_line(character_string, offsets): return "".join([chr(cord + number - 26) if 65 <= cord <= 90 < cord + number or 97 <= cord <= 122 < cord + number else chr(cord + number) for cord, number in zip([ord(x) for x in character_string], [int(x) for x in offsets])])
```

Test them all out:

```
string, offsets, offsets2 = "abcdefgh", "11111111", "48151623"
print(code_char_string(string, offsets), code_char_string_compact(string, offsets), code_char_one_line(string, offsets)) 
# bcdefghi bcdefghi bcdefghi
print(code_char_string(string, offsets2), code_char_string_compact(string, offsets2), code_char_one_line(string, offsets2)) 
# ejdiflik ejdiflik ejdiflik
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're doing some cesar-cipher encryption.

Here is a simplified version:

```
def code_char(text, shift):
    a = ord('a')
    return ''.join(
        chr((ord(char) - a + shift) % 26 + a) if 'a' <= char <= 'z' else char
        for char in text.lower())

print code_char('abcdefgh', 1)
>>> bcdefghi
```

This allows you to be more dynamic:

```
print code_char('rstuwxyz', 1)
>>> stuvxyza
```

It's important to remember ASCII codepoints *start* after 26:

```
>>> ord('a')
97
```

So you will still need to use ordinals which is why I set `a = ord('a')` allowing you to pass strings *without* having to specify a 'string' list or offsets.

Comment: thank you drewness! But at the moment i'd rather to stick to what i know, even if my version is long winded, it makes sense to me as each step is done step by step, rather than in less chunks.